# Intraday Factor Analysis, measuring intraday alpha, etc

Tags: high-frequency, fama-french, high-frequency-estimators

I understand that models like the Fama-French 3 factor model are sometimes regressed against portfolio returns to compute an intercept value to understand if the portfolio captures common factors or 'has alpha.' Meaning, individuals can regress a portfolio against these factors to measure alpha: [example](http://faculty.london.edu/aedmans/Rowe.pdf)

I have had trouble finding literature related to use of factors to measure alpha or understand returns in context of intraday trading. For example, if I have a strategy that holds a security or group of securities for 1 hour or 2 hours every so often, how would I measure the alpha of this strategy? Regressing the daily FF factors would not make sense in this context.

How would a high frequency trader of say large cap stocks know if they have a truly profitable strategy or are just capturing factors on a short time frame?

Can anyone please provide information on the use of intraday factors/understanding intraday returns of short-term strategies. Any readings or insights?

I have read about the eeps effect which seems to make this even more challenging.

Comment: One of the factors could be trade imbalances as in Chordia and Subramayam (2000)

Answer (score 2):

I will start by coming back to the concept of alpha: it exists jointly with the concept of beta, and both terms are related to the coefficient of a linear regression of the returns of a strategy on "benchmarks" that are meant to be "non diversifiable risks" or "open source returns":
$$r(t) = \alpha(t) + \sum_k \beta_k F_k(t) + \epsilon(t).$$

The first "factor", corresponding to a **non diversifiable risk** is the **market factor*: you make money on average (if you believe on capitalism via listed markets) if you invest on main indices like S&P500, FTSE100, DAX30 or CAC40. But you will suffer from large drawdowns if you invest on it.
The good news is that **the non diversifiable risk is often easy to hedge** with future, hence the remaining returns are easy to synthesise: keep your strategy as it is and hedge it with a future (I know it does not really make sense for intraday strategies because the transaction costs of such a hedge might be high).

Fama and French, and in fact the 300 factors listed in the excellent "[... and the cross-section of expected returns](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/29/1/5/1843824)" paper by Harvey, Liu, and Zhou are **Open source strategies**. Most often they have a lot of biases, have not been backtested with transaction costs (see "[Stock market liquidity and the trading costs of asset pricing anomalies](https://www.cfasociety.org/france/PublishingImages/Pages/ConferencesandEvents/Stock%20Market%20Liquidity.pdf)" by Raboun, Briere, Nefedova and L for details about transaction costs of FF factors.) but they are considered to be accessible to a lot of investors and traders, hence a "valuable" strategy should be orthogonal to them.
Or if you want to think about this differently: open source strategies may be overcrowded, and **you do not want to be exposed to crowded strategies** (see "[Modeling Transaction Costs When Trades May Be Crowded: A Bayesian Network Using Partially Observable Orders Imbalance](https://www.icmagroup.org/assets/Uploads/Bayesian.pdf)" in Machine Learning for Asset Management: New Developments and Financial Applications (2020) by Raboun, Briere, Nefedova and L again --yes, I recently developed an interest for these concepts ;{)}--).

What is the equivalent for **intraday strategies**?

- for should you have easily access to a **market component** that is the Future of the local cap weighted index: the E-mini for instance.
- you can even have access to **ETFs tracking sectoral benchmarks**; that may be good because at high frequency speed, I would rather think that a drop of a sector is easily diversifiable.
- you could also simulate for yourself "open source" intraday strategies like **mean reversion** or **orderbook imbalance**, as it is suggested in one comment, to be sure to not invest on crowded strategies.
  It makes sense for intraday strategies, nevertheless you probably (and in any case you should) **check the liquidity available for your intraday strategy in your backtests**. Thus I suspect that you are already orthogonal to most open source and crowded strategies if your modelling of liquidity is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I was wondering if one could use a simple market making algorithm or another "standard" trading agent behavior like zip60 Zero-Intelligence Traders (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1640270) to be one of the factors. Similarly identify other trading agent behavior which is orthogonal to other agent behaviors.